# Unresolved reference: viewModel at Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I want to realise a tutorial of YouTube which implements a calculator app in Kotlin for Android.
They use there a viewModel, I did it exactly like in the video but get this error:

> Unresolved reference: viewModel

The codeline for this looks like this:
`val viewModel = viewModel<CalculatorViewModel>()`

And my viewModel is like that:

```
class CalculatorViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var state by mutableStateOf(CalculatorState())
}
```

When I hover over the error I get these hints:
[Suggestion of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC2kH.png)

As mentioned above, I tried to implement this calculator app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-aTcFJWxEQA&t=965s and did exactly the same.

Comment: Hover over the red text and see if a menu pops up that allows you to tell the IDE to import the `viewModel` function for you. You might need to add this library to your app's `build.gradle`: `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0'`

Comment: I added the dependency to my library but I still get the error